# App Inventor cannot connect to emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, app-inventor

Started evaluating *MIT App Inventor* (ver 2.2) on *Windows 7* (from *Administrator* account). Since I don't have Android devices, I have to use an *emulator*.

*aiStarter.exe* and *emulator.exe* both work when explicitly started, but 
when I start *aiStarter.exe* and [ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/#5440960545685504](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/#5440960545685504) on *Chrome* and then do `Connect/Emulator,` *emulator.exe* is not started, and *aiStarter* disply messages like:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Dec/2014 04:15:13] "GET /echeck/ HTTP/1.1" 200 38
The system cannot find the path specified.
Problem checking for devices : status 1
```

I tried disabling *Chrome extensions*, and trying to start [ai2.appinventor.mit.edu](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/#5440960545685504) from *FireFox* and *Maxthon* browsers, with identical negative results.
Both Googling and searching [appinventor.mit.edu](http://appinventor.mit.edu/) didn't help.

1. What is the failed path in the error message referring to?
2. Any suggestions how to debug App-Inventor/emulator startup failure?

Comment: see the troubleshooting suggestions here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NbJRyCA9udxdU3oNyadR0fuvNglijYR7X3mVB_ZIeNU/pub

Comment: Thanks @Taifun, I did read that document but finally (see my answer below) gave up on debugging and decided to go with a clean reinstall (religiously accepting all App Inventor 2's defaults).

Comment: kill the .adb in task manager as explained in this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29207717/ai2-mit-emulator-dont-launch-companion/29207991#29207991

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no remedy seemed to help, I decided to start from a clean slate.

I went to http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/update-setup-software.html and followed "How to Update the App Inventor Setup Software"

1. Uninstalled current App Inventor
2. Booted my machine
3. Downloaded the latest Windows installer from http://appinv.us/aisetup_windows
4. Installed the AppInventor_Setup_Installer_v_2_2 (1).exe that I downloaded, accepting all the installer's defaults. The installation directory was chosen by the installer in C:\Program Files (x86)\AppInventor
5. Logged out and after logging in again - aiStarter is running
6. Killed all the BlueStack processes
7. Tried Connect/Emulator. Emulator won't start, though it's not failing as previousely
8. Started emularor using run_emulator.bat
9. After a few tries, finally emulator is syncing with App Inventor 2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my windows 7 compyter and what I did is

- manually delete the AppInventor in C:\Program Files (x86)
- reboot
- start a new install