# MIT App Inventor 2: emulator doesn't launch companion

Tags: android, emulation, windows-7-x64, app-inventor

When I run `aiStarter.exe` as administrator, and the click on connect to the emulator in http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu, then the emulator starts, the black screen with android is displayed and after a couple of seconds I get the android home screen.

Then every couple of seconds, a line "127.0.0.1 - date/hour/ "GET/echeck/..." is added in `aiStarter.exe`, and on http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu the message asking me to wait a minute or two while it's starting emulator remains. I have waited for something to happen at this point for 30 minutes, but nothing changes.
[image]

If I understood it well, the companion should be automatically launched and then I should be asked if I when to update it. But this never happens, it is as if emulator get stuck just before companion get launched, or App Inventor never recognizes that emulator has started.

Comment: By the way if you want to use Genymotion (much faster Android emulator): [How can I use Genymotion with App Inventor 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27976467/395857)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this trick, didn't try yet, but seems a really good alternative!

Comment: Genymotion does work  for most of the task (and is much faster) but unless you pay some fees (monthly) you won't be able to access all your device feature. cf http://i.imgur.com/uSzQFPr.png or https://www.genymotion.com/#!/pricing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simple fix to that bug:

once your emulator is loaded (just wait until you see that: pct1), don't close anything, just open Windows Task Manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> -> `Task Manager`) in the process kill the adb.exe (**while the emulator is working**) cf. pct2. Don't do anything else, wait for few second and you will see a new popup to [this site](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/)  saying that it has detected the emulator. Repeat that each time the emulator stuck.

pct1:

[image]

pct2:

[image]

This seems to force adb to listen on the port 8001

EDIT1 an other way to kill and restart adb.exe:

List item:

1. put your UAC (in start menu) at the lower level
2. launch your emulator, when it's ready (SD card prepared) do the
   following
3. go in `C:\Program Files (x86)\AppInventor\commands-for-appinventor`
   right click new and "text" and rename this file `run.bat` (to change
   .txt in .bat)
4. right click to edit the file with notepad
5. write just: `CMD`
6. save and close
7. now double click that `run.bat` file
8. write: `adb kill-server`
    (press <kbd>enter</kbd> and wait)
9. write: `start-server`
      (your emulator should now connect)

Edit2: Genymotion works much faster with app inventor 2.